# Angular App works great but ngMock NOT loading Modules properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-ngmock

## My app works fine when i deploy it and run it in a browser

I can successfully reach all my controllers/services. and they were linked together via submodules.

I used submodules to organize the states/routes better for ui-router.  (Previously we had ALL of our states in the app dot js file. There were like 50. Now they're organized out into smaller modules).

**app.js**   [Module file]

```
var phpApp = angular.module("phpApp",
[
    "ui-router"
    "phpApp.components" , ...

]).config(...).run(...);
```

**components.js**  [Module file, contains states/routes]

```
var ComponentModule = angular.module("phpApp.components",
[
    "ui-router"
    "phpApp.components.user" , 
    "phpApp.components.client"
     ...

]).config(...).run(...);
```

**user.js**    [Module file, contains states/routes]

```
var UserModule = angular.module("phpApp.components.user",
[
    "ui-router"

]).config(...).run(...);
```

**user-controller.js**   // LOADS fine; is a controller.

```
angular.module('phpApp.components').controller('UserController', ....);
```

**client-controller.js**  // does **NOT** load!  Cannot find 'phpApp.components' module...

```
angular.module('phpApp.components').controller('ClientController', ...);
```

My index.html file loads the scripts in this order:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="components/components-module.js"></script>
<script src="components/user/user-module.js"></script>
<script src="components/client/client-module.js"></script>
...
<script src="components/user/user-controller.js"></script>
<script src="components/client/**client-controller.js**"></script>
```

I dont get it.  My client-controller loads AFTER my user-controller... yet it is not able to locate the proper module?

I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'phpApp.components' 
is not available! You either misspelled the module name or 
forgot to load it.
```

I am very confused and frustrated at this point.  I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer lies in the karma config file** (karma.conf.js by default)

The answer, as expected, was a simple one.

I had a rule to include all JavaScript files:

```
"app/app.js",
"app/components/**/*.js",
```

You will need to make sure you rewrite your load rules to load all module JS files first:

```
"app/app.js",
"app/components/**/*-module.js", <-- modules must load first
"app/components/**/*.js",
```

To help expound, i have my project set up where:

```
1) controllers are in their respective xxx-controller.js files, 
2) ervices are in xxx-service.js files and 
3) modules are in xxx-module.js files
```